# Custom button help on Event

Tags: custom-button

I have custom object Demo and i added a custom button to list view on open activities, it's working as expected except it's not returning the record type i want, what did i do wrong?

```
/00U/e?
RecordType = 0120b000000QOro&
what_id={!Demo__c.Id}&
retURL=%2F{!Demo__c.Id}
```

Comment: Are those spaces intentional? That might be the cause.

Comment: Thank you that removing the spaces solved the problem, i didn't know spaces could be issue in url button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces in URL parameters can cause problems, so avoid using them in your URLs unless they are meant to be there. If you want line breaks in your URLs for legibility, you might consider using URLFOR:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Event.new, null, [
    RecordType=0120b000000QOro,
    what_id=Demo__c.Id,
    retURL='/'&Demo__c.Id])}
```